# How can I find the input from a list which yields the maximum result from some query in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: algorithm, prolog, idioms

I'm just picking up Prolog now, so I'm unfamiliar with the normal way of doing most things.

Essentially I have a rule which gives a value from an input:

```
ScoreFromInput(Input, Score) :- ...
```

And I have a list of inputs, which are just numbers. I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the input which yields the maximum score.

This is what I have right now, but I think it recurses infinitely:

```
bestInput(BestInput) :-
    %#Bind the list of valid inputs
    legalInputs(ValidInputs),
    %# -1000 is a dummy score, it should get replaced on the first call to bestInputHelper
    bestInputHelper(ValidInputs,-1000,BestInput).

%#I think this rule should work if the first input in the list is not the best one
bestInputHelper([Input|RestOfInputs],BestScore,BestInput):-
    bestInputHelper(RestOfInputs,RestBestScore,BestInput),
    ScoreFromInput(Input,BestScore),
    RestBestScore > BestScore.

%#And this one if it is the best input
bestInputHelper([Input|RestOfInputs],BestScore,Input):-
    bestInputHelper(RestOfInputs,RestBestScore,_RestBestInput),
    ScoreFromInput(Input,BestScore),
    RestBestScore =< BestScore.
```

This is what I have so far, but I imagine there is a much more straightforward way of doing it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: One thing about Prolog naming is to start predicates with a lowercase letter (uppercase or underscore starts variable names).  So I changed ScoreFromInput to scoreFromInput in my answer.

Comment: @hardmath: Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out. In my actual program, that is the case. I just switched things to "input" and "score" here so that their purpose is clear to someone unfamiliar with my program, and I guess I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to state it is that an input is best if there is no better input:

```
best_input(Best) :-
    legal_inputs(Inputs),
    member(Best, Inputs),
    input_score(Best, Score),
    \+ ( member(Better, Inputs), input_score(Better, S), S > Score).
```

To see what is wrong with your own code, try for example SWI-Prolog's graphical tracer:

```
?- gtrace, best_input(Best).
```

And please_use_readable_names inSteadOfUnreadableOnes.

Answer (score 3):

Despite Chris's lack of familiarity with Prolog, the approach he outlined may be a more efficient way of finding the input with the maximum score than mat's.  Instead of doing a quadratic number of comparisons, an approach like Chris's is possible that linearly scans the possible inputs.

Here **maxScoreOfList/3** will return the best item Z and the best score B for a list of valid inputs as the third argument.  The predicate will fail on an empty list.

```
maxScoreOfList(Z,B,[H|T]) :-
    scoreFromInput(H,S),
    maxScoreOfListAux(Z,B,H,S,T).
```

A "helper" function is needed as follows, which illustrates the "trick" of adding some extra arguments so that when the end of the input list is reached, the outputs Z and B can be bound to the best item and score found "so far":

```
maxScoreOfListAux(Z,B,Z,B,[ ]).
maxScoreOfListAux(Z,B,X,S,[H|T]) :-
    scoreFromInput(H,Q),
    (   S >= Q
     -> ( Y = X, R = S )
     ;  ( Y = H, R = Q )
    ),
    maxScoreOfListAux(Z,B,Y,R,T).
```

Comment: Ahh, interesting way of doing things! Thanks for the alternate method. Luckily, my program is dealing with inputs small enough for a quadratic algorithm (24 maximum), but I can certainly see this being more useful for bigger inputs. Also, I suppose this is the correct way of doing what my code was meant to do. Thanks!